# Resuming Android countdown timer

Tags: android, timer

I have been trying to code for a countdown timer with CountDownTimer, and make it able to resume from the stop time. So far I was able to refer to the other question and come up with this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    getResume();

    if ( getResume()==0) {
        countDownTimer.start();
        timerHasStarted = true;
        startB.setText("STOP");
        setResume(1);
        Toast.makeText(this, getResume()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (getResume()==1) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timerHasStarted = false;
        startB.setText("RESTART");
        setResume(2);
        Toast.makeText(this, getResume()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (getResume()==2){
        CountDownTimer rcdt = new MyCountDownTimer(s1, interval);
        rcdt.start();
        setResume(1);
    }

}
```

So getResume() is just to get global int resume, which I thought I could use to act as a switch, since timerHasStarted was not helping me very much. However, since I am creating the new timer when resume is 2, I was not able to resume the timer more than once. This code only let me resume once because it is different timer, and after rcdt.start() happens I can't even .cancel(). Clearly I am missing an important concept, but I could not find out by searching.
https://gist.github.com/bverc/1492672 unlike this case, I just make the milisuntilfinished = s1, and using it to start new timer. Is this way to go? or is there some way to make the code above work?
 Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace this line (in your if==2)

```html
        CountDownTimer rcdt = new MyCountDownTimer(s1, interval);
```

with

```html
countDownTimer= new MyCountDownTimer(s1, interval);
```

let me know if its works and fi you udnerstood what was the problem, if it was the problem but you didnt understood what was wrong I will post explanation.

Comment: It works! Although I have another question. countDownTimer= new MyCountDownTimer(s1, interval); what does this line actually do? Does it reconstruct countDownTimer with different parameter? (s1, interval)?

Comment: Well do you know some OOP (Object Oriented Programming)?  If not its really important for you to learn it.  but shortly think that countDownTimer is your variable like "String s1 = 'some value'". What you did with "rcdt" is creating NEW object, like creating String s2 = 'some value'.  The line you replaced was like doing s1 = 'some other value'.

Comment: Make total sense! Thank you!